# running php scripts on Apache and Microsoft SQL server on Windows 7 (64 bits)

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

I have access to a web server. What all do I need to have installed in my 64 bit, Windows 7 OS desktop to run php scripts? I already have MS SQL server 2008 installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I get setup for PHP development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931543/how-should-i-get-setup-for-php-development)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `xampp` or `wamp` it will help you setup `php`, `apache` and `mysql` on windows and then if you don't want to connect to `mysql` connect to your `mysql` via `php` script.